# Add-on installed but not showing in sidebar (Blender 2.92)

Tags: add-on

I am trying to use blender to do my animations for unreal engine. To do this, I installed the addon [Mr Mannequins Tools](https://github.com/Jim-Kroovy/Mr-Mannequins-Tools) (which is compatible with Blender 2.92) as a zip. After installing it and ticking the checkbox, it does not show up in the sidebar. I've tried reinstalling blender and downloading the zip file and installing the addon again, but it still does not show up.

Here is how it looks on my screen - you can see that I have enabled the addon but it is still not showing up on the sidebar.

It would be great if someone could provide me with some assistance.

[image]

Comment: I've never used that addon (though I know it used to be quite popular among UE4 users) - is it supposed to put a tab in the sidebar, or are the options accessible from the Add menu?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Woah im dumb its under the add thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Please post this as answer.

Comment: When you activate an addon, the field "Location" tells you where you'll find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addon's can put their tools in different places - It seems the Mr. Mannequin addon does not add a tab to the sidebar of the Number Panel, but rather, the tools for Mr. Mannequin Templates can be accessed from the *Add Menu*.